# Conditional expectation setup

Tags: conditional-expectation

Suppose $\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1$ are iid random variables with density $f$ and cdf F and $c\in R$. Then why is:
$$E[\epsilon_1|\epsilon_1+c>\epsilon_0]=
\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x F(x+c) f(x) \text{d}x}{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F(x+c) f(x) dx}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because

\begin{align}
E\left[\epsilon_1\mid \epsilon_1+c>\epsilon_0\right]&=\frac{E\left[\epsilon_1\mathbf1_{\epsilon_1+c>\epsilon_0}\right]}{P\left[\epsilon_1+c>\epsilon_0\right]}
\\\\&=\frac{\iint x\mathbf1_{x+c>y}f(x)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y}{\iint\mathbf1_{x+c>y}f(x)f(y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y }
\\\\&=\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x+c} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x+c} f(y)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}
\end{align}